# Error during ROOT installation

Tags: root

When installing ROOT this error occurred. How to fix it?

```
cint/cint/lib/stream/iostrm.h:24:10: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: What version of ROOT are you trying to build, and what are your Ubuntu and gcc versions?

Comment: What is ROOT? I never heard from this as a software.

Comment: @peterh I am assuming https://root.cern.ch/

Comment: Wow, thanks! As far I know, C++ code uses `#include <iostream>` and doesn't `#include <iostream.h>` since around a decade. It will probably hard to compile this source, although it could be also a useful package creation project, too.

Comment: Yes that is most likely the issue - see for example [Build failure with gcc 5.1.0: trying to include iostream.h](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/build-failure-with-gcc-5-1-0-trying-to-include-iostream-h/19363) (which is why I asked about **versions**)

Comment: i am installing 5 34/36 version

Comment: root is a package for the data analysis of particle physics